# VMware tools installations in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, vmware, archlinux

I want to install VMware tools on Arch Linux, but when I click to install VMware tools and when I try to find it in "/media/cdrom" , I do not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing the VMware tools using [Pacman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacman_%28package_manager%29).

A list of the various packages is in [the Package Database, VMware](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=vmware).

Comment: As of today, the main packages `open-vm-tools` and `open-vm-tools-dkms` are flagged as out-of-date because of compatibility issues with kernel 3.10. It is totally unclear whether these are going to be fixed any time soon.

Comment: open-vm-tools is broken on current kernels on arch... There is a [bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/37026) opened, you can vote for it and contribute if you like